# Библиотека не зарегистрирована. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))

Tags: sql, sql-server

При попытке создать запрос и хранимую процедуру в SQL Server 2014 Management Studio выдает, что библиотека не зарегистрирована.

Диаграммы создает и открывает.

Проблема появляется во второй раз. Первая была где-то полгода назад. Точно удалял раздел {91A74EB0-EFA0-482B-B43C-35CFC74B275F}. Но тогда и на диаграммах ошибку выдавал.

[В соответствии с этой статьей](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/2849799/library-not-registered-error-message-when-you-open-a-new-query-window)

Пошел искать раздел {91A74EB0-EFA0-482B-B43C-35CFC74B275F}, его, конечно же, не нет, потому что удалял его.

Дальше предложено зарегестрировать библиотеку, но у меня нет следующего файла (в прошлый раз тоже вроде не было): 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regtlibv12.exe

Искал на всем диске через поиск, не нашел.

Так же у меня на компьютере стоит Visual Studio 2019. В прошлый раз вроде помогла ее переустановка (удалил 2017 и поставил 2019).

Сейчас тоже удалил ее и установил заново, переустановил SQL Server 2014. Не помогло.

[Нашел этот ответ](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be5ddbb6-6cf1-4dc9-af6f-8838274da585/ssms-typeelibnotregistered?forum=sqlexpress):

> В качестве вашего описания, ваш компьютер не имеет
>   regtlibv12.exe. Regtlibv12.exe является частью .Net framework
>   4 (.NET 4.0), и .NET 4.0 является требованием для SQL Server 2014, он
>   может быть установлен при успешной установке SQL Server 2014 express.
>   Как и мой анализ, ваш regtlibv12.exe может быть поврежден. Я
>   рекомендую вам восстановить [Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135)
>
> После ремонта, regtlibv12.exe будет существовать в пути (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regtlibv12.exe).

Запустил инструмент восстановления 
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

> C:\WINDOWS\logs\cbs\cbs.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\FixDotNet.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\NetFxSetupEvents.txt
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_dotNetFx40_Full_setup_decompression_log.txt
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_dotnetfx40_full_x86_x64_decompression_log.txt
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU_decompression_log.txt
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_NDP471-KB4033342-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU_decompression_log.txt
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_NetFxRepairTool_decompression_log.txt
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_BackgroundDownload_20190908140301.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_BackgroundDownload_20190908140301_00_setup.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_BackgroundDownload_20190908140301_00_setup_errors.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_BackgroundDownload_20190908140301_result_Success.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_BackgroundDownload_20190908201306.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_BackgroundDownload_20190908231150.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_BackgroundDownload_20190908231150_00_setup.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_BackgroundDownload_20190908231150_00_setup_errors.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_BackgroundDownload_20190909100648.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_BackgroundDownload_20190909115041.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_BackgroundDownload_20190909152225.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_BackgroundDownload_20190909152225_00_setup.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_BackgroundDownload_20190909152225_00_setup_errors.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_BackgroundDownload_20190909152225_result_Success.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_BackgroundDownload_20190909164423.log
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft .NET Framework 4
>   Setup_20190909_150816966.html
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft .NET Framework 4
>   Setup_20190909_151521259.html
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1
>   Setup_20190909_151613583.html
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.1
>   Setup_20190909_151441651.html
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\FixDotNet_HKCR_Installer.regdump
>
> C:\Users\nykil\AppData\Local\Temp\FixDotNet_HKLM_Installer.regdump

Пытался последнее обновления для 2014 ставить.

И все. Что делать дальше не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Полностью удалил 2014 версию и почистил за ней хвосты. Поставил 2017.